# Normal derivative of the First Dirichlet eigenfunction

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, eigenfunctions, maximum-principle

Good afternoon.

My question is related to the Maximum principle. In fact:

We consider $\Omega\subset(M,g)$ a bounded domain in a Riemannian manifold and we  consider the first Dirichlet eigenfunction $u$ associated to the first Dirichlet eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of the Laplacian $\Delta$, i,e $$\begin{cases}
\Delta u&=\lambda_1u~~~~ in ~~~~\Omega\\
u&=0 ~~~~~~~~over~ \partial\Omega
\end{cases}$$
My question is: Does $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}$ is $>0$ or $<0$ over $\partial\Omega$ where $\nu$ is the outward unit normal to $\partial\Omega$ ?

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure. But as I know, the first eigenfunction is positive in $\Omega$, if $\Omega$ is likely a ball. So $\frac{\partial u }{\partial\nu}$ should be negative over $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: @lanse7pty Thank you for your comment. I now that $u$ is positive either on $\Omega\subset M$, Can you please show me how the normal derivative should be negative over the boundary. \

Comment: By the definition of normal derivative,roughly, for any $x_0\in \partial \Omega$,  $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x_0)=\lim\limits_{|x-x_0|\rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x_0)-u(x)}{|x-x_0|}\le 0$.